# Unlimited width css grid with auto row

Tags: css, css-grid

I need to create auto width css grid with break to new line after each 8 element.

I can not **change html** markup and **use flex** css property. Do this with css grid property.

[image]

I can’t do reverse for the second row, so that it starts with a narrow card, as in the design.

```css
.block-instagram {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 225px);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 368px 225px);
  grid-gap: 2px;
}
.block-instagram__item {
  background: #e3e3e3;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-instagram">
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

I expect that you can at least change `css`, although this solution seems a bit *hacky*.

```css
.block-instagram {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 225px);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 225px 143px 225px);
  grid-gap: 2px;
}
.block-instagram__item {
  background: #e3e3e3;
}
/* This rule targets odd-numbered elements in items 1 to 8 */
.block-instagram__item:nth-child(-n + 8):nth-child(odd) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
/* This rule targets even-numbered elements in items 9 to Infinity */
.block-instagram__item:nth-child(n + 9):nth-child(even) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-instagram">
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
  <div class="block-instagram__item"></div>
</div>
```